# Allowing words picked up in regex in certain cases only

Tags: regex

I have a regex expression to look for people just sticking "N/A" or similar into a form field.

```
^(?!(\b(N/A|NA|n/a|na|Yes|yes|YES|No|no|NO)\b))
```

Probably not the most elegant I am sure. However I cannot for the life of me get it to allow the above words if followed by something.

So if someone just types "yes" then I want it to fail the regex check. But if someone types "yes, I have blah blah etc etc" I want it to pass.

The expression I have allows the word to be used as long as it isn't the first word in the sentence. I just want to disallow the listed words as the ONLY words in the field.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps something like `(yes|N\/A|no|NA)(?!$)(.*)` . Live regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/yJaUbQ/3). Note that you can use the case insensitive flag to avoid having to write `No` and `no` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may remove the first `\b` (it is redundant between the start of string and a word char) and replace the second one with `$` (end of string):

```
^(?!(?:N/A|NA|n/a|na|Yes|yes|YES|No|no|NO)$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0RT2I5/1)

With a case insensitive option, you may reduce the pattern to

```
^(?!(?:n/?a|yes|no)$)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0RT2I5/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string, then...
- `(?!(?:n/?a|yes|no)$)` - a location in string that is not immediately followed with `n/?a` (`na`, `n/a`), `yes` or `no` that are followed with the end of string.

In human words, only the start of string is matched if the whole string is not equal to the alternatives inside the alternation group.

Comment: This seems to work the best for what I need. Thanks.
Is there also a way to make the check fail until they have added at least 3 characters?

Comment: Ok so as far as making them type at least 3 characters this seems to work

^(?!(?:N/A|NA|n/a|na|Yes|yes|YES|No|no|NO)$)[a-z,A-Z,0-9]{3,}

(Again, probably making some people cringe at the sight of it)

Comment: The original one you posted passed with 'y' or 'ye' on the way to failing with 'yes'
I needed a way of failing the check until at least 3 characters were typed. So I figured [a-zA-Z0-9] would be all chars and {3,} was 3 or greater.

Comment: @Munnzie_D If you want to "live-validate" those strings, use [`^(?!(?:n/?a?|y(?:es?)?|no?)$)`](https://regex101.com/r/0RT2I5/3).

Comment: Thanks. Works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to match all the forbidden strings exactly and invert the result.

Try `^(n/?a|yes|no)$` with a case-insensitive option and invert the result.
`^` matches the beginning of the string. `$` matches the end of the string.

When you don't have a case-insensitive option, use `^([nN]/?[aA]|[yY][eE][sS]|[nN][oO])$`.